# How to Create following String Dynamically

Tags: java, json, recursion

I am doing project using **Lucen** library in here I need to build query dynamically using **Json** object. so in here I use jettison library. as an example my json like this

`{"OR":{"OR": {"fildKey1": "value1","fildKey2": "value2","fildKeyabc": "valueabc"},"AND": {"AND": {"fildKey3": "value3","OR": {"fildKey4": "value4","fildKey5": "value5"}},"fildKeyw": "valuew"}}}`

using above json I need to create following query

```
(( fildKey1 : value1 OR fildKey2 : value2 OR fildKeyabc : valueabc )OR(( fildKey3 : value3 AND( fildKey4 : value4 OR fildKey5 : value5 ))AND fildKeyw : valuew ))
```

but I can't get the above query.my result is like this

```
(( fildKey1 : value1 OR fildKey2 : value2 OR fildKeyabc : valueabc )OR(( fildKey3 : value3 AND( fildKey4 : value4 OR fildKey5 : value5 )AND)AND fildKeyw : valuew )OR)
```

I need to remove above extra 2 operators this is my code

```
public class JettisionCls {
   static Stack s = new Stack();
   String operater = null;
   static String res = "";
   int bracket_counter = 0;   


public void getKeyAndValue(JSONObject json_obj) throws JSONException{
    Iterator<String> iter = json_obj.keys();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String obj = iter.next();
        if(obj.toLowerCase().equals("and") || obj.toLowerCase().equals("or")){
            //System.out.print(obj);
            operater = obj;              
        }

        JSONObject temp = null;
        try {
            temp = new JSONObject(json_obj.get(obj).toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        if (temp != null) {
            //System.out.print("(");
            res = res +"(";
            bracket_counter=bracket_counter+1;
            s.push(operater);

            getKeyAndValue(temp);

            //System.out.print(")");
            res = res +")";
            bracket_counter=bracket_counter-1;                          
            if((s.size()) != 0 && bracket_counter != 0){
                //System.out.print(s.peek());
                s.pop();
                res = res +s.peek(); 
            }
            else{
                s.pop();
            }
        }            
        else{
            if(iter.hasNext()){
                res = res+" "+obj + " : " + json_obj.get(obj) + " " + operater;                                    }
            else{
                res = res+" "+obj + " : " + json_obj.get(obj)+" ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my main method look like this

```
String multiLevelQuery = "{\"OR\":{\"OR\": {\"fildKey1\": \"value1\",\"fildKey2\": \"value2\",\"fildKeyabc\": \"valueabc\"},\"AND\": {\"AND\": {\"fildKey3\": \"value3\",\"OR\": {\"fildKey4\": \"value4\",\"fildKey5\": \"value5\"}},\"fildKeyw\": \"valuew\"}}}";

JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(multiLevelQuery);
JettisionCls obj = new JettisionCls();
obj.getKeyAndValue(jobj);
System.out.println(JettisionCls.res);
```

if anyone can please help me.

Comment: @Afrin this one also work for simple query. also I can't see any bug in here.if it has please explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using string replacement.

```
public void createQry(String s){
    String temp = s;

    if(temp.contains(")OR)")){
        temp = temp.replace(")OR)", "))");
    }
    if(s.contains(")AND)")){
        temp = temp.replace(")AND)", "))");
    }
    System.out.println(temp);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is an interesting problem. But instead of brute force, I would have gone with something more elegant like `recursion`. The pushing, popping and concatinating will be done by recursion for you. In your code, I can see a lot of places where it can break. Even if you fix this issue, there is a chance that it will fail for another condition.

A sample algorithm with recursion would be

```
public String generateQuery(JSONObject json_obj) {

if(single_json_obj)
   return generated_query_for_single_condition;

//else complex json with inner children
else
   return generateQuery(innerJSONObject)
}
```

}

Comment: @Afrin He has already used recursion, but it wasn't enough to get the expected result